# If $\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\arcsin(nx)}dx=c_n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^2c_n}=?$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}\frac{\arctan(nx)}{\arcsin(nx)}dx=c_n$$

Find the value of 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n^2c_n}$$

I tried integrating the expression but couldn't. Need help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the substitution $u=nx$ to get

$$\int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^1 \frac{\arctan u}{\arcsin u} \frac{1}{n} \; du.$$

Then, $\arcsin(1) = \pi/2$ and $\arctan(1)=\pi/4$.  For large $n$, you're integrating on a tiny interval close to $1$, so your integrand is very close to $1/2$.  So you should have

$$c_n \approx \int_{\frac{n}{n+1}}^1 \frac{1}{2n} \; du = \frac{1}{2n(n+1)},\,n^2c_n\approx\frac{n}{2(n+1)},$$

which would make your limit equal to $1/2$.

So you have to argue that "very close" really does cause a good enough $\approx$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question but it seems right.

Comment: +1 for nice approach. The justification can be given via mean value theorem for integrals. we have $$c_{n} = \frac{1}{n(n + 1)}\cdot\frac{\arctan \xi_{n}}{\arcsin \xi_{n}}$$ where $n/(n + 1) < \xi_{n} < 1$. Thus as $n \to \infty$ we have $\xi_{n} \to 1$ and hence $n^{2}c_{n} \to 1\cdot (\pi/4)/(\pi/2) = 1/2$.